# QGIS 3.28 and LAStools issue - lasinfo not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: qgis, las, lastools

I'm trying to run one of LAStools open source commands on a .laz file I have.
I have installed the plugin in QGIS v. 3.28, and have downloaded the LAStools-master folder available through GitHub (https://github.com/LAStools/LAStools). In the documentation they say that the 'lasinfo' algorithm is open source.

In processing, I've set the LAStools value to the LAStools-master directory, but am not able to use any of the functions.

Can't seem to find any recent solutions, and all solutions from 2+ years ago aren't working for me.

Something I noticed that may or may not be of interest, is that running lasinfo runs from 'LAStools\bin\lasinfo -i', but the C++ code for the function is in LAStools\src?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a "LAStools-master" directory, you probably downloaded [master.zip](https://github.com/LAStools/LAStools/archive/refs/heads/master.zip) which contains the source code only, not the executables. Go to the [release](https://github.com/LAStools/LAStools/releases/tag/v2.0.2) page, download LASTools.zip and point the QGIS processing plugin at the extracted directory (not the bin subdirectory).